# How to show that the degree of this field extension is 12?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I need to show that $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},2^{1/6}):\mathbb{Q}]$ is a field extension of degree $12$. It is possible to show that the degree is at least $12$ because it is divisible by $6$ and $4$ by finding the minimal polynomial of the simple field extensions of $2^{1/4}$ and $2^{1/6}$, but I am not sure how to bound the inequality in the other direction.

Another way to approach this problem might just be to explicitly find the basis, but I think there should be a way to find a bound on the inequality.

Answer (score 3):

You've already done the hard work. Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}, 2^{1/6})$, let $\alpha = 2^{1/12}$, and let $L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Clearly, $K \subset L$, since $2^{1/4} = \alpha^{3}$ and $2^{1/6} = \alpha^{2}$. You've already shown that $[K:\mathbb{Q}] \geqslant 12$, and it's not hard to show (e.g., via Eisenstein) that $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 12$ by computing the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $K$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace of $L$, we conclude that $[K:\mathbb{Q}] \leqslant 12$, which gives the desired equality.

Comment: hi Alex, so just to make sure the logic is correct for the final step since 12=[L:Q]=[L:K][K:Q], we have that [K:Q] must divide 12, and hence (by a theorem from number theory) it must be <= to 12.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use Eisenstein: to show that $[L:\mathbf Q]\leq 12$, it is enough to find any nonzero polynomial of degree $\leq 12$ whose root is $\alpha$, so this is overkill. Also, it's pretty easy to see that $K=L$.

Comment: @William that's certainly one way to go about it. But in general, it's a basic result in linear algebra that if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then $W$ is finite dimensional, and $\dim(W) \leqslant \dim(V)$.

Comment: @tomasz sure, that's fair, although I wouldn't call Eisenstein overkill, considering that it's almost certainly used earlier in the problem to compute the degrees of $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}), \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/6})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Either way, we can agree your argument is nice and is simpler.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I meant that using this to prove that $[K:\mathbf Q]\leq 12$ is an overkill, not for the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

(1) $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ since $2^{1/4}$ satisfies *irreducible*
polynomial $x^4-2$ of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

(2) $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/6}):\mathbb{Q}]=6$ since $2^{1/6}$ satisfies *irreducible*
polynomial $x^6-2$ of degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

(3) From degrees of extensions  $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/6})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, none of them is contained in other.

(4) $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2})$ is contained in both fields, and again, $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

(5) From (3) and (4), $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}) \cap \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/6})$ is precisely $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2})$.

(6) Draw lattice diagram of fields $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}, 2^{1/6})$, $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/6})$, $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ and (intersection) $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2})$ [looks like  diamond].

Degrees of parallel sides are same; you can easily deduce your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Degrees of field extensions are multiplicative. Can you find $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}):\mathbb{Q}]$ by explicitly producing the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/4}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Not too hard. You'll find the degree of this extension is $4$.

Then can you find $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},2^{1/6}):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})]$ by finding the minimal polynomial of $2^{1/6}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$? Since you know the degree of the full extension should be $12$, the degree of this extension should be $3$. So perhaps a polynomial of degree $3$. To show that the polynomial you get is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$, simply find its roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and note that they do not lie in $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of [Q(2^1/4,2^1/6):Q(2^1/4)] should be $x^3-\sqrt2$ right? 2^1/6 is a root and the other 2 roots are complex so it is irreducible in the field Q(2^1/4)

Comment: Yes, that is correct!